# toggling css class does not change visibility value

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a popup form using CSS and JavaScript only.

here is the my HTML page:

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style>
.popup-form {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-form .show {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="popup-form show" id="myPopup">
  <form>
    <div class="w3-container">
      <br> <input class="w3-input" placeholder="Enter category name" />
      <br> <input class="w3-input"
        placeholder="Enter category discription" />
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-right">
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit">Add</button>
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit">Cancel</button>
    </div>

  </form>
  </div>
  <div onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle w3-button"></i></div>
</body>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
      popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
</script>
</html>
```

I can see in the console that the .show class is toggled, but visibility stays hidden. So what I'm i missing?

Comment: Change `.popup-form .show` to `.popup-form.show` .There should not be any space between `.popup-form` and `.show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

Since the classes `popup-form` and `show` are in the same element, you need to change the below CSS.

**CSS:**

```
.popup-form {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-form.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Here the second CSS means. Take the element, which has both the classes `popup-form` and `show`. Before what you were doing was:

```
.popup-form {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-form .show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Take the element, which has a parent element `popup-form` and take the child which has `show` class.

**Snippet:**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popup-form {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-form.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
<div class="popup-form show" id="myPopup">
    <form>
        <div class="w3-container">
            <br> <input class="w3-input" placeholder="Enter category name" />
            <br> <input class="w3-input"
                placeholder="Enter category discription" />
        </div>
        <div class="w3-container w3-right">
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit">Add</button>
            <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-round-large" type="submit">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
<div onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle w3-button"></i></div>
</body>

<script>

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Naren, not only did you give me the solution, but you explained my error

Answer (score 5):

Currently, you are using

```
.popup-form .show {
visibility: visible;
}
```

but you have to use like this

```
.popup-form.show {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

extra space is the problem.

`.popup-form .show` vs `.popup-form.show`

```css
<style>
.popup-form {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.popup-form.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```